# Can I mix Python dataframe positional index and column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can I get an entry in dataframe using negative/positional index and column name? For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[3,4,5]})
# df is:
#    a  b
# 0  0  3
# 1  1  4
# 2  2  5
df.iloc[-1]['a']  # got 2
df['a'].iloc[-1]  # got 2
df.loc[1,'a']     # got 1
df.loc[-1,'a']    # got KeyError: -1
```

Comment: No you can't mix both within the same `iloc`/`loc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, use `df.columns` and `get_loc`, to convert column header label to index location:

```
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('a')]
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning, that even though both suggested solutions above work for data **lookup**, they differ for data **assignment**.

While

`df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('a')] = 42`

will work as expected

`df.iloc[-1]['a'] = 42`

will result in [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't mix both within the same `iloc`/`loc` (this used to be the case with the now deprecated [`ix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) indexer)

The correct approach would be one of the double slice:

```
df.iloc[-1]['a']
```

*Note that the "issue" is not specific to negative positional indices. When you do `df.loc[1,'a']` you are **not** slicing per position, but per **name**. This would also fail with a `KeyError` if you had no `1` in the index.*

Comment: Thanks. That is clear. I could use df.loc[1,'a'] since it just happens 1 is a row index, not a row position.